# How to create a procedure like SetLength that also zeros the memory?

Tags: delphi, memory, initialization

In some cases I need to set size of a dynamic array and then fill it with zeros.

Something like:

```
procedure SetLengthAndZero(VAR X; NewSize: Integer);
begin
   SetLength(x, newsize);
   if newsize > 0
   then FillChar(x[0], length(x)* SizeOf(x[0]), 0);
end;
```

But the code above (obviously) won't compile.

---

In [Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984789/whats-in-the-memory-of-a-dynamic-array-when-used-with-setlength-in-delphi/3984913), the content of the memory is undefined after SetLength.

Comment: I know that SetLength is 'compiler magic'.

Comment: You need to know element size. And if X already has allocated size and is managed, you will have problems.

Comment: In Delphi 2010+ you could decare procedure `SetLengthAndZero<ItemType>(VAR X: TArray<ItemType>; NewSize: Integer);`

Comment: @Rigel, I rolled back your edit, since the edit changed what was asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read Embarcadero's [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength):

> ```
> procedure SetLength(var S: <string or dynamic array>; NewLength: Integer);
> ```
>
> For a dynamic array variable, SetLength reallocates the array referenced by S to the given length. Existing elements in the array are preserved and newly allocated space is set to 0 or nil.

This means that `SetLength` is all you want.

---

If you want to clear the whole dynamic array, not just allocate more items and preserve existing items, just call `SetLength`with `NewLength = 0` before calling it again with the wanted length.

A generic solution:

```
Type
  TDynArrayTool = record
    class procedure ClearAndSetLength<T>( var arr : TArray<T>; newLen : Integer); static;
  end;

class procedure TDynArrayTool.ClearAndSetLength<T>(var arr: TArray<T>;
  newLen: Integer);
begin
  Setlength(arr,0);
  SetLength(arr,newLen);
end;
```

Comment: And. if you wanted to ensure that setting the size of an already existing dynamic array zeroed all the elements, you might want to SetLength with NewLength = 0, before setting to the required length, to avoid preserving existing non-zero elements.

Comment: @Rigel, yes that is what is said in the documentation. I amended the answer with a clarification.

Comment: Call it twice in the same proc, that still answers your question. If you have a different requirement that would require a different answer, ask a different question.

Comment: @LuRd-Sorry. I forgot to accept this answer. But later is better than never :)

Comment: In Delphi 7, the content of the memory was undefined after SetLength. Does anyone knows when this changed? (Which Delphi version?)

Comment: @Gravity, as far as I can tell, expanding a dynamic array has zeroed the newly allocated memory since at least since Delphi 5. The documentation however, have not been consistant though.